# How to Retrieve HTML block from within XML document w/ PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

I have an XML document with no CDATA tags and embedded HTML.  How do I extract this HTML to manipulate it in PHP for display?

Example:

```
<?xml ...>
<main>
 <book>
  <title>Title of Book</title>
  <description>
   <p>Paragraph 1 describing book.<br />blah blah</p><p>2nd Paragraph</p>
  </description>
 </book>
</main>
```

I want to extract `<p>Paragraph 1 describing book.<br />blah blah</p><p>2nd Paragraph</p>` into a variable.  Or echo to display in php using simpleXML.

I tried:

```
$test = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlfile);
echo $test->{'main'}->{'book'}->{'description'};
```

and I just get a blank line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first transfer `special symbols` in `xml`

reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

And this could work.

```
$xml=<<<MMT
<main>
 <book>
  <title>Title of Book</title>
  <description>
   <p>Paragraph 1 describing book.<br />blah blah</p><p>2nd Paragraph</p>
  </description>
 </book>
</main>
MMT;
$xml = preg_replace('@<p>(.*?)</p>@','&lt;p&gt;$1&lt;/p&gt;',$xml);
$xml = str_replace('<br />','&lt;br /&gt;',$xml);
$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$str = $data->book->description;
$str = preg_replace('@&lt;p&gt;$1&lt;/p&gt;@','<p>(.*?)</p>',$str);
$str = str_replace('&lt;br /&gt;','<br />',$str);
echo $str;
```

OR BETTER WAY, if you only have one loop, you can insert `<![CDATA[` `]]>` for standard xml data formart:

```
$xml=<<<MMT
<main>
 <book>
  <title>Title of Book</title>
  <description>
   <p>Paragraph 1 describing book.<br />blah blah</p><p>2nd Paragraph</p>
  </description>
 </book>
</main>
MMT;
$xml = preg_replace('@<description>(.*?)</description>@is','<description><![CDATA[\\1]]></description>',$xml);
$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$str = $data->book->description;
echo $str;
```

Comment: This XML comes from a 3rd party, they are unable to add the CDATA, but adding the way you have seems so obvious now, I just modified to accept attributes in the <description> tag regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$test = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlfile);
echo $test->{'main'}->{'book'}->{'description'}->asXML();
```